# Are dragons of higher quality (Legendary, Epic, etc) stronger in battle?

Tags: dragon-city

Are dragons of higher quality (Legendary, Epic, etc) stronger in battle than their common peers?

Answer (score 1):

Yes yes they are.

Based on personal experience, I have a two silver star Terra Dragon and a two silver star Elements Dragon(common versus rare) who differed in attack damage and health. My common dragon had around 4k health while the Elements dragon had double that health. In battle, when both are using untrained Earth moves, The Elements Dragon did around 3.5k damage normally and the Terra did only about 2k damage (both using Eartgquake).

So naturally, higher rarity dragons will be more powerful than those below them in rarity.